# Create MBTiles from geojson in raster format

Tags: raster, gdal, ubuntu, mbtiles, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to create raster file in the **Mbtiles** format.

I tried ,

```
$ gdal_rasterize -ot Byte  -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ts 4950 4090 -of MBTiles station.geojson station.mbtiles
```

I'm using,

> $gdalinfo --version : GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01

**Error:**

> ```
> > ERROR 1: Cannot find min and max zoom_level
> > 
> > ERROR 6: Could not find an appropriate zoom level that matches raster
> > pixel size
> > 
> > ERROR 6: Only EPSG:3857 supported on MBTiles dataset
> > 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
> > 
> > ERROR 6: IWriteBlock() not supported if georeferencing not set
> > 
> > ERROR 6: IWriteBlock() not supported if georeferencing not set
> > 
> > ERROR 6: IWriteBlock() not supported if georeferencing not set
> ```

**EDIT:**

`$ ogrinfo station.geojson -so -al`

> INFO: Open of 'stations.geojson' using driver 'GeoJSON' successful.
>
> Layer name: OGRGeoJSON
>
> Geometry: Point
>
> Feature Count: 86
>
> Extent: (-77.272622, 38.766522) - (-76.842038, 39.119927)
>
> Layer SRS WKT:
>
> GEOGCS["WGS 84",
>
> DATUM["WGS_1984",
>
> ```
>    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
>
>        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
>
>    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
> ```
>
> PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
>
> ```
>    AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
> ```
>
> UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
>
> ```
>    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
> ```
>
> AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
>
> name: String (0.0)
>
> marker-color: String (0.0)
>
> marker-symbol: String (0.0)
>
> line: String (0.0)`

Comment: What does `ogrinfo station.geojson -so -al` show?

Comment: @user30184 I updated my question as you requested ogrinfo of my geojson

Comment: The projection you are using is 4326 but MBtiles are only working with 3857 (https://epsg.io/3857) as stated in the error message. You should reproject it first.

Comment: thank dan_ke, I converted to EPSG 3857 using ogr2ogr . But still I am  getting Below error regarding zoom, ERROR 6: Could not find an appropriate zoom level that matches raster pixel size
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 6: IWriteBlock() not supported if georeferencing not set
ERROR 6: IWriteBlock() not supported if georeferencing not set
ERROR 6: IWriteBlock() not supported if georeferencing not set

Comment: you can use https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe to convert the `GeoJSON` to an `.mbtiles` file.Check this tool

Comment: Francisco Raga, I tried but it support only vector files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that this is the case, but GeoJSON is not supposed to be any coordinate reference system (CRS) except for WGS (EPSG:4326).

I think you'd better convert it to a Shapefile first. While you're at it, convert it to the right projection:

```
 ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" station.shp station.geojson -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

Now what worked for me was rasterizing to TIFF first:

```
gdal_rasterize -ot Byte -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ts 100 100 -of MBTiles station.shp station.mbtiles
```

(Note I changed the resolution... play with the `-ts` parameter.)

And now convert that tiff to MBTiles:

```
gdal_translate station.tiff station.mbtiles -of MBTILES
```

Output from my dataset of points across Tasmania loaded fine in QGIS, and ended up with this demonic view, strangely:

[image: Tasmania light up with red]

Comment: Alex, I am also facing same blur issue, Might be resolution not working!!

Comment: Hey @Abhi, you can change the resolution with the -ts option. Make those numbers higher!

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer in gdal-dev mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-December/047904.html.

> The error message says it all, doesn't it ? MBTiles only accepts a
>   single tiling scheme, with a pre-defined set of zoom levels /
>   resolutions. By default, when gdal_rasterize will initialize the
>   output raster, the chance that it fits to those constraints is
>   extremely unlikely.
>
> Now you may wonder why you can gdal_translate an arbitrary raster as
>   MBTiles. This is because MBTiles (similarly to GeoPackage with a
>   predefined tiling scheme) sheat in its CreateCopy() implementation to
>   invoke the warping engine to reproject/resample to one of the
>   compatible zoom level.
>
> But gdal_rasterize use the Create() interface, so this isn't possible.
>
> Obvious workaround: rasterize to TIF and translate to MBTiles.

It seems to be possible to make gdal_rasterize to write directly into MBTiles file if the resolution matches the tiling schema. I guess that it is possible to solve the resolution mathematically but I just made the initial conversion into TIFF, then into MBTiles, and then I checked with gdalinfo what the pixel size is. With the same pixel size this command did create a MBTiles file despite the error about min and max zoom_level.

```
gdal_rasterize -ot Byte  -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -tr 9.55462853
5647032 9.554628535647032 -of MBTiles points_3857.json points_3857_2.mbtiles
ERROR 1: Cannot find min and max zoom_level
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```